# Issues with timeline animation

Tags: java, javafx, timeline.js

so I am trying to create a snowman and animate its left and right arm, I have looked at the Oracle docs and tried to write my time as closely as possible to how the example sets it.

For reference, this is the code example I was looking at:

```
final Rectangle rectBasicTimeline = new Rectangle(100, 50, 100, 50);
rectBasicTimeline.setFill(Color.RED);
...
final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(rectBasicTimeline.xProperty(), 300);
final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), kv);
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
timeline.play();
```

Now, here is my code for creating the left arm, and (if it worked) animating it. Where is my flaw and how can I fix it?

```
private void drawLeftArm(GraphicsContext gc)
    {
        leftArm = new Ellipse();
        leftArm.setCenterX(90.0);
        leftArm.setCenterY(160.0);
        leftArm.setRadiusX(100.0);
        leftArm.setRadiusY(30.0);

        gc.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);
        gc.fillOval(leftArm.getCenterX(), leftArm.getCenterY(),     leftArm.getRadiusX(), leftArm.getRadiusY());

        timeLine = new Timeline();
        timeLine.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeLine.setAutoReverse(true);


        KeyValue LeftValue = new KeyValue(leftArm.centerYProperty(), 100);
        KeyFrame keyFrame  = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), LeftValue);

        timeLine.getKeyFrames().addAll(keyFrame); 
        timeLine.play();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted, you created `leftArm`, but did not add it to the scene graph. As a result, it is animating, but not visible. The `fillOval` call above is equivalent to

```
gc.fillOval(90.0, 160.0, 100.0, 30.0);
```

in the sense that it does not have any reference to `leftArm`. So you did two (independent) things: painted an oval to the canvas and started animation of an invisible ellipse.

For animations, don't use `Canvas`/`GraphicsContext`. Just use a [Group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) or [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) as a parent for the animated nodes.